# :how to split single values of a column into two and return the values along with the length

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table 'test' with first name, last name in name column. How do i split first name, last name and also return the length of first name and last name. 
example:

```
name
hello world
Thomas Edison
Christopher Columbus
```

I want the result as:

```
First_name    FirstName_length    last_name    LastName_length
hello          5                   world       5 
Thomas         6                   Edison      6
Christopher    11                  Columbus    8
```

Comment: I'd like to know what query you have tried before asking this question.

Comment: if it works. mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

```
select split_part(name,' ',1) as first_name,
 length(split_part(name,' ',1)) as firstname_length,
 split_part(nme,' ',2) as last_name, 
 length(split_part(name,' ',2)) as lasttname_length from table_name
```

Comment: Thanks everyone this query worked for me given by sqlfiddle:   select substr("name", 1, instr("name", ' ')-1) first_name,
       length(substr("name", 1, instr("name", ' ')-1)) First_Name_length ,
       substr("name",instr("name", ' ')+1) Last_Name,
       length(substr("name",instr("name", ' ')+1)) Last_name_length
from table_name

Answer (score 1):

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/679c03/13).. for the same

Just replace your table_name and column_name with actual names

```
select substr("name", 1, instr("name", ' ')-1) first_name,
       length(substr("name", 1, instr("name", ' ')-1)) First_Name_length ,
       substr("name",instr("name", ' ')+1) Last_Name,
       length(substr("name",instr("name", ' ')+1)) Last_name_length
from table_name
```

O/P

```
FIRST_NAME  First_LENGTH    LAST_NAME   LAST_LENGTH
hello            5           world      5
Thomas           6           Edison     6
Christopher     11           Columbus   8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select First_name, length(First_name), Last_name, length(Last_name) from test
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dbb84/5/0)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i have a column 'name' and i want to split the values and also get the length of each . In above query column name is not mentioned so it won't be applicable

Comment: the op is not asking for that